# PyCharm code style for string auto-formatting

Tags: python, pycharm

I have trouble to create useful/clean code style in PyCharm that won't destroy my code when I do the code auto-formatting.

In general I want my string to look like that:

```
message = ("There are " + str(avd_instances) + " AVD instances about to be created according to set, "
           "but there were only " + str(requested_ports_to_use_num) + " ports ")
```

Or like that:

```
raise MyException(
    TAG,
    "There are " + str(avd_instances) + " AVD instances about to be created according to set, "
    "but there were only " + str(requested_ports_to_use_num) + " ports "
)
```

But what I get is something like this:

[image]

Or something like this:

[image]

It is simply ugly and there is a chaos. There are much worse cases too.

Currently my Code Style looks like this:
[image]

If you have other proposition how can I format my code to make it "compatible with PyCharm" and clean I would be glad to hear.

Comment: turning off `Align when multiline` should make it look like your second preference, no?

Comment: I have turned off all `Align when multiline` and it doesn't change a thing. It is always formatted like I have presented.

Comment: I'd also like to know a solution to this.